# IPreviewHandler and TIFF files

Tags: c#, delphi, preview

I am trying to write a standard way of previewing files, using the IPreviewHandler interface. I can get at viewers for most for most file formats I am interested in, but not .tiff files. My registry doesn't have a .tiff\shellex{..} entry. However Windows 7 does show a preview in Explorer.

Is it using another viewer, or is there somewhere else I should look?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've just found registration item into *SystemFileAssociations\.tiff\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\ShellImagePreview*

The CLSID of it is FFE2A43C-56B9-4bf5-9A79-CC6D4285608A, but I still don't know is it IPreviewHandler or not

Comment: This CLSID belongs to the Windows photo viewer, which can be used to open files for (pre)view. As far as I know Windows 7 does not contain any `IPreviewHandler` for general image formats. In case you want a ready-to-use control for .Net using `IPreviewHandler` but also supporting images check out this: http://www.jam-software.de/shellbrowser_net/file-preview.shtml